# Distinct not working?

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, sqlplus

I need to insert some field in a table. The table:

```
    CREATE TABLE RADAR(
    ctfoto  VARCHAR2(5),
    pkradar NUMBER(3,0),
    sradar  VARCHAR2(3),
    limitvelctera   NUMBER(3,0),
    limitvelradar NUMBER(3,0),  
    CONSTRAINT radar_pk PRIMARY KEY(ctfoto, pkradar, sradar)
);
```

The insert operation:

```
INSERT INTO RADAR(ctfoto, pkradar, sradar, limitvelctera, limitvelradar)
SELECT distinct carretera_foto, pto_km_radar, sentido_radar, limit_vel_ctera, limit_vel_radar FROM gotcha
```

The error:

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (USER4704.RADAR_PK) violated
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DISTINCT` applies to the entire set of columns you are selecting.

In all probability, you have rows in `GOTCHA` that have the same `carretera_foto`, `pto_km_radar`, and `sentido_radar` values but different values for one or both of the other two columns (`limit_vel_ctera` and `limit_vel_radar`).  The `DISTINCT` in your `SELECT` cannot eliminate either of the rows because at least one value is different but the primary key constraint on the `RADAR` table rejects rows where the first three columns are identical.

Comment: Fixed!!! the other two values of the table Radar are unique to (each radar has it's own top speed so i use the whole thing as primary key.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have more than one record in `gotcha` with the same values in fields `carretera_foto, pto_km_radar, sentido_radar`.

`DISTINCT` means the whole record will not be repeated.

Comment: Yes, it is. Isn't distinct used to discart the repeated records?

Comment: And i need to discart the repeated values and take just one. How do i do that?

Comment: That's another question :) Seriously, you should ask a new question for that. When you do, make sure you state which values of limit_vel_ctera and limit_vel_radar you should consider when you have more than one record with same carretera_foto, pto_km_radar, sentido_radar